# How to center the text to the middle of a button?

Tags: css

I have this button I am trying to make, but I am unable to get the text to be centered. I have previously looked at what past people have answered on how to align text within a button, but the ones I have tried do not seem to work.

```css
  .btn1 {
    width: 160px;
    height: 40px;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline;
    border-radius: 60px;
    background-color: white;
    border-color: #05434a; 
    border-width: 3px;
    box-shadow: 5px 6px #05434a;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1.7vh;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-family: poppins;
    padding: 0px;
    }
    
    .nd {
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    .social-link {
      text-align: center;
      margin-top: 20px;
      margin-bottom: 0 !important;
    }
```

```html
  <div class="social-link">
    <a class = "nd" href = "">
      <button class="btn1">
        <p>text</p>
      </button></a>
  </div>
```

Comment: The text is centered in your button

Comment: In what way is this NOT centered?

Comment: Remove the paragraph tag from inside your button tag. That's not semantic html. The text is centered.

Comment: Likewise links should not contain `buttons` or `inputs`.

Comment: Your HTML is not 'legal' - perhaps get that sorted first? Try running it through a validator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While one thing that seems OK is centering of the text, your HTML has these problems:

> Error: The element button must not appear as a descendant of the a
> element.
>
> Error: Element p not allowed as child of element button in this
> context

So this snippet removes these two elements and moves the CSS button styling onto the anchor element. It makes this inline-flex to help center the text.

Note: the text is centered though it can sort of appear as if it's a bit high because of the visual strength of the shadow. This snippet puts a 1px width border on the element just so you can assure yourself the text is centered.

```css
.btn1 {
  width: 160px;
  height: 40px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-flex;
  border-radius: 60px;
  background-color: white;
  border-color: #05434a;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  box-shadow: 5px 6px #05434a;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.7vh;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  font-family: poppins;
  padding: 0px;
}

.nd {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.social-link {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="social-link">
  <a class="nd btn1" href="">
        text
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

Well, pretty easy and always works:

```
    display: flex;
    justify-contect: center;
    align-item: center;
```

that will get the job done

for the

element, set:

```
    text-align: center;
```

Comment: In the code the OP provided the text is already centered

Comment: So what you are looking for?